# Messaging: Lots of RemoteServices methods or Unique message builder/interpreter?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, client-server

Hey guys,
I'm using GWT to code a simple multiplayer board game.
And while I was coding the question came up to my mind:

At first I though my client could simply communicate with the server via RemoteServices calls, so if a client wanted to connect to a game he could do as follows:

- joinGame (String playerName, String gameName)

And the server implementation would do the necessary processing with the argument's data.
In other words, I would have **lots of RemoteService methods**, one for each type of message in the worst case.

I thought of another way, which would be **creating a Message class** and sub-classing it as needed.
This way, a single remoteService method would be enough:

- sendMessage (Message m)

The messages building and interpreting processing too would be done by specialized classes.
Specially the building class could even be put in the gwt-app shared package.

---

That said,
I can't see the benefits of one or another. Thus I'm not sure **if I should do one way or another or even another completely different way.**

One vs other, who do you think it is better (has more benefits in the given situation)?

EDIT: A thing I forgot to mention is that one of the factors that made me think of the second (sendMessage) option was that in my application there is a CometServlet that queries game instances to see if there is not sent messages to the client in its own message queue (each client has a message queue).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) in this case (something like your `sendMessage()` concept).

If you have one remote service method that accepts a Command, caching becomes very simple.  Batching is also easier to implement in this case.  You can also add undo functionality, if that's something you think you may need.

The [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/) project is a great framework that brings this pattern to GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Messaging takes more programmer time and creates a more obfuscated interface.  Using remote service methods is cleaner and faster.  If you think there are too many then you can split your service into multiple services.  You could have a service for high scores, a service for player records, and a service for the actual game.

The only advantage I can see with messaging is that it could be slightly more portable if you were to move away from a Java RPC environment but that would be a fairly drastic shift.